# OAuth 2.0 REDIRECT URI

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, uri

my UpdraftPlus Backup/Restore was working and backing up to Google drive. 
But now the  REDIRECT URI has changed on the Google Cloud Console Side.

it should end with
/options-general.php?page=updraftplus&action=updraftmethod-googledrive-auth

however it keeps truncating after the Ampersand and shows up like

/options-general.php?page=updraftplus

any help on how to set the right URI?

Comment: I was able to get the right URI by using the old console. I am still having problems with the new one. Any way to confirm it is a problem with google's new code and how to tell them?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem yesterday. It looks like a bug of Google Cloud Console to me. I managed to solve this by using "percent-encoding" in the URL for the ampersand symbol. Ampersand symbol shall be encoded as %26. So you shall enter your url the following way:

/options-general.php?page=updraftplus%26action=updraftmethod-googledrive-auth

Another option you could try (but I don't think it will be necessary) is to swith back to the old view. It looks like that in the old interface there is no problem with ampersand. The link to the old interface is at the left bottom corner (it is quite hard to find it).

By the way I've also described this solution [here](http://igor-stupak.blogspot.ru/2013/11/google-cloud-console-redirect-uri.html) (but it is in Russian :)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest UpdraftPlus release, we worked around this by only having one parameter in the URL!

Best wishes,
David